# Showing text messages in augmented reality applications with ARToolkit

Tags: opengl, opencv, augmented-reality, artoolkit, flartoolkit

I would like to implement a simple AR desktop application. This application should first recognize a marker out of a set of pre-registered ones, and then, show on screen some particular information related to the detected marker.

I was thinking on using ARToolkit, even if it is quite old and not anymore supported.

1. Do you think ARToolkit is a good solution?
2. How can I show text messages on screen using ARToolkit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an interesting article here http://mycodelog.com/2010/03/23/printw/.

It easily explains how to implement a "printw" function that works exactly like printf.

Comment: This solution is anyway kind of ugly.

Answer (score 0):

[osgART](http://osgart.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) could be helpful http://osgart.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page